# Why can't a long integer be converted to an integer when inside a Python list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, integer, long-integer

I have seen many posts here, which gives ways of removing the trailing L from a list of python long integers.
The most proposed way is

```
print map(int,list)
```

However this seems not to work always.

Example---

```
A=[4198400644L, 3764083286L, 2895448686L, 1158179486, 2316359001L]
print map(int,A)
```

The above code gives the same result as the input.
I have noticed that the map method doesn't work whenever the number preceding L is large, and only when the numbers are in a list. e.g. Application of int() on 4198400644L *does give* the number without L, when out of the list.

Why is this occurring and more importantly, how to overcome this?

I think I really *need* to remove this L, because this is a small part of a program where I need to multiply some integer from this list A, with some integer from a list of non-long integers, and this L is disturbing.I could ofcourse convert the long integers into string,remove the L and convert them back to integer.But is there another way?

I am still using the now outdated Python 2.7.

Comment: Why does the `L` suffix concern you? Can you not just do the multiplication... and then whenever you `print` or output it as a string then you won't see the `L` anyway... you're only seeing it because you're seeing the `repr` of the object

Comment: Please just use Python3. Splitting integers into `int` and `long` is an implementation of Python2 detail that you should not bother with. Large integers are always `long`, you are merely looking at the representation wrongly - containers force `repr` on their elements, print uses `str` for bare values instead.

Comment: Compare ``print sys.maxsize + 1``, ``print int(sys.maxsize + 1)``, ``print repr(int(sys.maxsize + 1))``. Note that it looks like you are using a 32-bit build of Python – on a 64-bit build ``int`` ranges from ``-9223372036854775808`` to ``9223372036854775807``.

Answer (score 1):

Python has two different kinds of integers.  The `int` type is used for those that fit into 32 bits, or -0x80000000 to 0x7fffffff.  The `long` type is for anything outside that range, as all your examples are.  The difference is marked with the `L` appended to the number, but only when you use `repr(n)` as is done automatically when the number is part of a list.

In Python 3 they realized that this difference was arbitrary and unnecessary.  Any `int` can be as large as you want, and `long` is no longer a type.  You won't see `repr` put the trailing `L` on any numbers no matter how large, and adding it yourself on a constant is a syntax error.

Comment: Note that the size of int is not 32-bit. It depends on the build, and seems to be the same as the pointer size (e.g. 64 bit on a 64 bit build).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi interesting note.  I prefer to work with Python 3 and not care.